# ?Does SQL Server 2016/2019 Web Edition supports encryption

Tags: amazon-web-services, sql-server, sql-server-2008, encryption, sql-server-2016

I trying to find out if SQL Server 2016 and 2019 Web Edition
supports encryption (on AWS)?

any help will be appreciated.

Thank you,
Moshe

Answer (score 1):

Yes, SQL Server 2016 and 2019 Web Edition supports encryption on AWS.

If you're running SQL Server 2012–2019 Enterprise Edition or 2019 Standard Edition, you can use Transparent Data Encryption (TDE) to achieve encryption at rest. You can set up encryption at rest by using AWS Key Management Service (AWS KMS) encryption keys. For more information, see [Encrypting Amazon RDS resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.Encryption.html).